# C Socket program doesn't print desired output (No Error)

Tags: c, sockets, networking, server, client

I can't seem to print what I enter in my client. I have compiled both without any error. Can't figure out why it isn't printing the desired output.

Q. What is wrong with my code ? How can I print a string with whitespaces through the client in the server.

Here is the code for the server.

```
/* Server Side program */


    int sid,nid;
    struct sockaddr_in q;
    char x[100];

    int len=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    sid=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    q.sin_family=PF_INET;
    q.sin_port=1600;
    q.sin_addr.s_addr=0;

    bind(sid,&q,len);

    listen(sid,20);

    while(1)
    {
            memset(x,0,sizeof(x));
            nid=accept(sid,&q,&len);
            read(nid,x,100);
            printf("%s\n",x);

    }
```

Here is the code for the client.

```
/*client side program*/


    int sid,status;
    struct sockaddr_in q;
    int len=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    char x[100];

    sid=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
            q.sin_family=PF_INET;                   
            q.sin_port=1600;                        
            q.sin_addr.s_addr=0;                  
    status=connect(sid,&q,len);
    if(status==-1)
    {
            printf("Connection failure");
            exit(0);
    }

    while(1)
    {
            printf("Enter string to send : ");
            scanf("%[^\n]s",x);
            write(sid,x,strlen(x));
            if(strcmp(x,"bye")==0)
                     break;

    }
```

Comment: And what _is_  the desired output? And what is the _actual_ ouput? And what is your input?

Comment: Your code doesn't pay much attention to errors.  The `scanf()` call isn't checked; the `read()` and `write()` calls are not checked.  The scan-set notation `%[^\n]` is complete in its own right; the `s` you have after it is a literal `s`, not a part of the scan-set notation.  Of course, the `s` will never match because when the scan-set completes, the next character is a newline, not an `s` — or EOF. And after the first string is read, the next character in the input is a newline, so the next loop fails immediately in the `scanf()` (it returns `0`, not EOF), and …

Comment: I wanted to print a string with whitespaces suppose "Abhishek Das" but the server does nothing after I input it in the client , although both are running.  Could you change/modify the code for me if possible. I am kinda new to this. Thank You

Comment: Have you checked return  value of `write()` or did `perror()` ?

Comment: Also why `accept()` call in `while(1)` ? If its for multiple client-server, where is the mechanism to handle that in your code  ? Simply putting `accept()` in `while(1)` doesn't work.

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s",x);` will fail to read anything on the 2nd iteration.  Use `fgets()`.

Comment: The code fragments aren't an MCVE ([MCVE]); they're sub-minimal and hence incomplete.  That makes it fiddly and unrewarding for people to modify your code. They have to write a modest amount of code — even if it is just 'find the right selection of headers and add `int main(void) {` before and `return 0; }` at the end'.  It isn't clear that's all that's necessary — but if you made it into an MCVE, people might be more willing to help with "could you change/modify the code for me".  How have you debugged it?  Where are the print statements?  Or did you run the programs in a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

There is all kinds of problems with your code.  Lack of error handling.  Incorrect use of `printf()` and `scanf()`.  Resource leaks.

Try something more like this instead:

Server:

```
int main()
{
    int sid, nid;
    struct sockaddr_in q;
    char x[100];
    socklen_t qlen;
    ssize_t xlen;

    sid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sid < 0)
    {
        perror("socket failure");
        return -1;
    }

    q.sin_family = AF_INET;
    q.sin_port = htons(1600);
    q.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(sid, &q, sizeof(q)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind failure");
        return -1;
    }

    if (listen(sid, 20) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen failure");
        return -1;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        qlen = sizeof(q);
        nid = accept(sid, &q, &qlen);
        if (nid < 0)
        {
            perror("accept failure");
            return -1;
        }

        while ((xlen = read(nid, x, sizeof(x))) > 0)
        {
            printf("Received: '%.*s'\n", xlen, x);
        }

        if (xlen < 0)
            perror("read failure");
        else
            printf("client disconnected\n");

        close(nid);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Client:

```
int main()
{
    int sid, xlen;
    struct sockaddr_in q;
    char x[100];

    sid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sid < 0)
    {
        perror("socket failure");
        return -1;
    }

    q.sin_family = AF_INET;                   
    q.sin_port = htons(1600);
    q.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("server ip here"); // or INADDR_LOOPBACK (127.0.0.1)

    if (connect(sid, &q, sizeof(q)) < 0)
    {
        printf("connect failure");
        return -1;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter string to send : ");
        if (!fgets(x, sizeof(x), stdin))
            break;

        xlen = strlen(x);
        if ((xlen > 0) && (x[xlen-1] == '\n'))
        {
            x[xlen-1] = '\0';
            --xlen;
        }

        if (write(sid, x, xlen) < 0)
        {
            perror("write failure");
            break;
        }

        if (strcmp(x, "bye") == 0)
            break;
    }

    close(sid);

    return 0;
}
```